# Open Source or Freeware C code Metrics tool for Number of function Call Occurrences (Windows)

Tags: windows, gratis, c

I am trying to find a metric "Number of function Call Occurrences" in Freeware tool.
Here is my expectation description:

"This metric specifies the number of function calls in the body of a function.

Calls through a function pointer are not counted. Calls in unreachable code and calls to standard library functions are counted. assert is considered as a macro and not a function, so it is not counted."

Here are some examples:

Example 1:

```
unsigned char   test2(unsigned char index);
unsigned char   test3(unsigned char index);

unsigned char   test1(unsigned char index)
{
    unsigned char   temp;

    if (0 != test2(index))
    {
        temp = test3(test2(index));
    }
    else
    {
        temp = test3(test2(index + 1));
    }

    return (temp);
}
```

In this example, the number of call occurrences in test1 is 5 (test2 is 3 times and test3 is 2 times)

I tried to use the ***SourceMonitor*** tool but result is 2 instead of 5.
***Cscope*** is used in Linux. I am using Windows 10.

Can someone share some freeware tools to collect this metric? Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe SourceMonitor think it like 2 different functions called, not how often.